# Почему шаблон не видит переменную, которую видит контроллер (Angular)

Tags: angular, view, controller

У меня есть компонент:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {GlobalSeviceService} from '../services/global-sevice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-constructor-page',
  templateUrl: './constructor-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./constructor-page.component.scss']
})
export class ConstructorPageComponent implements OnInit {
  loading = false;

  constructor(
    public globalService: GlobalSeviceService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.transferConstructorData(this.globalService.myAnimal.animal_id, this.globalService.myAnimal.gender_id);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

  transferConstructorData(anim_id, gender_id){
    this.loading = true;
   
    this.globalService.loadCategoriesAndParts(anim_id, gender_id)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('response:', response);
        this.globalService.constructor_resp = response;
        this.globalService.categories = this.globalService.constructor_resp.constructor_page['categ_parts'];
        this.globalService.parts = this.globalService.constructor_resp.constructor_page['parts'];
        let j;
        let i = 0;
        for (j in this.globalService.categories) {
          if (this.globalService.categories[j].changeable){
            i ++;
            if (i === 1){
              this.globalService.categories[j].css_categ_active = true;
            }
            else {
              this.globalService.categories[j].css_categ_active = false;
            }
          }
        }
        // сохраняем текущие детали в myAnimal
        let k;
        let l = 0;
        for (k in this.globalService.parts) {
          if (!this.globalService.parts[k].changeable || this.globalService.parts[k].default){
            l++;
            this.globalService.myAnimal.my_parts[l] = this.globalService.parts[k];
          }
        }
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(this.globalService.myAnimal.my_parts);
      });
    }
  }
```

В методе transferConstructorData помимо прочего я загоняю данные в переменные, которые находятся в сервисе:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface MyAnimal{
  animal_id: number
  gender_id?: number
  my_parts?: Part[] 

}

export interface Category{
  id: number
  active: boolean
  animal_id: number
  bg_color_default: string
  bg_color_default_id: number
  categ_title: string
  changeable: boolean
  color_id: number
  have_body_color: boolean
  have_spec_color: boolean
  image: string
  required_detail: boolean
  spec_color_default: string
  spec_color_default_id: number
  subjoin: boolean
  z_index: number
  css_categ_active?: boolean
}

export interface Part{
  active: boolean
  categ_id: number
  categ_title: string
  changeable: boolean
  default: boolean
  have_body_color: boolean
  id: number
  layer_1_code_bg: string
  layer_2_code_outline: string
  layer_2_code_white:string
  layer_3_code_speccol: string
  layer_4_code_glare: string
  locked: boolean
  part_categ_id: number
  part_name: string
  subjoin: boolean
  bg_color_default: string
  spec_color_default: string

}



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalSeviceService {

myAnimal: MyAnimal = {animal_id: 0, gender_id: 0, my_parts:[]};

 categories: Category[] = [];
 parts: Part[] = [];

 constructor_resp: any;

 constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

loadCategoriesAndParts(anim_id, gender_id): Observable<Category>{
    return this.http.get<Category>('http://localhost:8000/constructor_page?anim_id=' + anim_id
    + "&gender_id=" + gender_id);
  }
}
```

Код шаблона:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let part of globalService.parts">
   <app-part  *ngIf="part.categ_id === categ2.id" [one_part]="part">
   </app-part>
</ng-container>

<app-pet *ngFor="let my_part of globalService.myAnimal.my_parts" [one_part]="my_part">
</app-pet>
```

Вопрос в следующем:
в методе transferConstructorData компонента после получения данных с сервера и распределения их в переменные сервиса, я успешно вывожу в console.log объект globalService.myAnimal.my_parts. Когда я пытаюсь получить элементы данного объекта в шаблоне, то получаю:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'layer_1_code_bg' of undefined
...
```

То есть шаблон просто не видит эту переменную.
При этом шаблон вполне нормально видит аналогичную переменную из сервиса (полученную в том же методе) globalService.parts
Почему у меня не получается вывести указанную переменную в шаблон?

Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел причину проблемы: globalService.myAnimal.my_parts - это объект, а объект вывести в шаблон нельзя. Я преобразовал этот объект в массив.

Сначала создаем в сервисе пустой массив:

```
myAnimalParts = [];
```

Далее производим преобразования:

```
for(let key in this.globalService.myAnimal.my_parts){  
      if(this.globalService.myAnimal.my_parts.hasOwnProperty(key)){  
        this.globalService.myAnimalParts.push(this.globalService.myAnimal.my_parts[key]);  
      }  
     }
```

[Источник решения проблемы тут](https://www.cloudhadoop.com/2018/08/typescript-how-to-convert-object-to.html)